# What is the syntax for mutualfriends using field expansion?

Tags: php, facebook, api

Using field expansion, for the first 3 friends, I want to find all the friends who are common.  How can I do it?

What should I change in this?

https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=friends.limit(3).fields(mutualfriends)&access_token=AAA...

Using single graph I can get the data using
/mutualfriend/userid

But I dont know how to pass the user id using field expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=friends.limit(3)**.fields(mutualfriends.user(1234567)**)

I think this will work for you where 1234567 is the userId of your friend.